# Finder aliases not recognized as symlinks on a Mac with node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, node-webkit, finder

I am running a nodewebkit application, and I want to search a folder for aliases.

The following code is working, but not recognizing folder aliases or file aliases as symbolic links.

Where am I wrong?

```
    var path = '/Users/test/Desktop/testfolder';
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
        if (err) return;
        files.forEach(function(f) {
            var newPath = path + '/' + f;
            console.log("looking for "+ newPath +" symlink: "+fs.lstatSync(path).isSymbolicLink());
            fs.lstat(newPath, function(err, stats){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                if(stats.isFile()){
                    console.log('is file mofo',f);
                }
                if(stats.isDirectory()){
                    console.log('is Directory mofo',f);
                }
                if(stats.isSymbolicLink()){
                    console.log('is symbolic link');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you talking about _Finder.app_ aliases? They are specific to that application and technically distinct from symlinks - you'd need an OS X-specific library for that, I presume.

Comment: Yeah that's what I just found out. Using mdfind is a way but i think it is smarter to just use swift. thx

Comment: If delegating to a shell command is an option - which is obviously slow - it _is_ possible to detect Finder aliases (come to think of it: that's what you implied by using `mdfind`); out of curiosity: how would you use `mdfind`? How are you planning to use Swift instead?

Comment: My application exists of two parts. One writte in swift and one with node-webkit. I cannot use wift in node.js but I can trigger a call and write semothing into a db. Using URLByResolvingAliasFileAtURL:options:error:

Comment: mdfind could be used with node-mdfind but the documentation is really bad so I am not really sure on how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Finder aliases* on OS X are technologically distinct from *symlinks*.

From the filesystem's perspective, they are regular files, and only Finder itself and the OS X-specific APIs know to handle them - Node.js has no built-in API for that.

IF calling out to the *shell* - which will be slow - is an option, you can try the following:

```
function isFinderAlias(path) {
  var contentType = require('child_process')
        .execFileSync('mdls', 
          [ '-raw', '-name', 'kMDItemContentType', path ], { encoding: 'utf8' })
  return contentType === 'com.apple.alias-file'
}
```

---

For a `swift`-based way to *resolve* a Finder alias to its *target path*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349364/45375).

Comment: thx good answer. but i cannot be sure that xcode or command-line is allways installed. Stillt right

Comment: @Silve2611: I've replaced the function with one based on `mdls`, which is a  standard utility (requires no installation) - hope that helps.

Comment: great solution! Thank you a lot!